# once defined variable keeps to be always undefined

Tags: jquery

```
$('.btnsG img').click(function(){
    if(typeof indexT === 'undefined') {var indexT = 1};
    indexT += 1;
    alert (indexT);
});
```

After loading the page and the first click alert is `2` and that's ok.

After each next click I expect to gradually change the variable to 3-4-5... because it is now not undifined, but the alert keep showing the value `2`!

What is wrong?

Comment: Javascript has function scope, so the variable is redeclared on each function call

Comment: That's so stupid. What is then the meaning of `if` in javascript !

Comment: Wait? Is that comment sarcastic or are you really asking that question?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, maybe it can be sarcastic, but it is true - `if` should be `if`. Try to explain in another way.

Comment: Well, maybe it is because english is not my native langage, but I don't quite understand what you mean... `if` is doing exactly what it should do. The variable scope too. You just probably didn't know about it...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, No, if once `indexT` becomes `1` it cannot be `undefined` on the next click. Or I missed something of elementary logic.

Comment: Edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25014945/2324107) to help you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initiating the variable in the scope, which mean it is a local variable. After the click event, your variable will not be defined for futur events.

Just move it outside your handler :

```
var indexT = 1;
$('.btnsG img').click(function(){
    indexT += 1;
    alert (indexT);
});
```

---

What you are dealing with here is the function closure. You are defining your variable inside your click handler. That mean futur event will not have access to that variable. Let work your code line by line :

```
$('.btnsG img').click(function(){ //Bind click event. You pass an anonymus function, creating a scope ON EVERY CLICK
    if(typeof indexT === 'undefined') //Check for var indexT in current and parent scopes. That variable is not define in any scope.
        var indexT = 1; //Assign indexT in the current scope (the one created every click)
    indexT += 1; //Add 1 to the variable.
    alert (indexT); //Alert
}); //Close the function, close the scope. Reference to indexT lost forever.
```

So, variable `indexT` is only defined inside click event and once that event is finish, it *disappear*.

Now let look the solution:

```
var indexT = 1;//Create a variable in that scope (currently the global scope) <------------------------------------------
$('.btnsG img').click(function(){ //Bind click event. You pass an anonymus function, creating a scope ON EVERY CLICK    |
    indexT += 1; //Add one to the first variable hit named indexT in the current and parent scope, which is this one ----
    alert (indexT);
}); //Close the click event scope
```

Now the variable is defined in the upper scope which mean it will not get defined on every click, but once on page load.

Comment: Karl, thanks a lot for your efforts. Everything is clear to me, but I need to establish a variable `onclick` and not on `pageload`. And of course need to use that variable on another click. And this is impossible, and that is very strange.

Comment: @bonaca then, take your current code and remove the keyword `var` before your variable. It will input it in the window object, which is a bad practice but if that's what you need, go for it!

Comment: Karl, yes, that's what I need. But why is that a bed practice? Declaring a variable by `pageload` is a `good practice` and declaring the same variable by click is - `bad practice`. Declaring a variable by clicking `should be so normal`. Much more normal then declaring it via pageloading. Anyway, once again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @bonaca that's because it is polluting the window object. every variable should be, if possible declared with `var`. What you could do is take you current code and add in the global scope ( i mean outside the function) **exactly** that : `var indexT;`. This will declare the variable but will not assign a value to it. It will be `undefined` **but** outside you window object.

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the variable out of that function, you are simply restricting its scope inside of that function, it causes to re declare that variable every time the function being called.

```
var indexT = 1;  
$('.btnsG img').click(function(){
    indexT++;
    alert (indexT);
});
```